# Jquery Auto Complette

Tags: jquery

This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Search.ashx',
    data: {
        q: "KAR",
        t: 'C'
    },
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function (source) {
    countriesArray = $.map(source, function (value, key) {
        return {
            value: value,
            data: key
        };
    }),
    countries = $.map(source, function (value) {
        return value;
    });
    $('.ACCity').autocomplete({
        lookup: countriesArray,
        lookupFilter: function (suggestion, originalQuery, queryLowerCase) {
            var re = new RegExp('\\b' + $.Autocomplete.utils.escapeRegExChars(queryLowerCase), 'gi');
            return re.test(suggestion.value);
        },
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            alert(suggestion.value);
        }
    });
});
```

This code is only running once and searching in current arrays. However, I want it to get the array every keypress.

[Source code](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete)

ps: i know i wrote  `q:"KAR"`. if i fix this problem i will change `$('.ACCity').val()`

thanks.

Comment: Its not clear what your asking.  What exactly is the problem you are having?  Is your server responding with the correct info?

Comment: firstly thanks.
yes. my server responding correct format. but this code running only once.  I want it to get the array every keypress.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the ajax call into the source property of your autocomplete:

```
$('.ACCity').autocomplete({
    ...

    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Search.ashx',
            data: {
                 q: "KAR",
                 t: 'C'
        },
        dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (source) {
            countriesArray = $.map(source, function (value, key) {
                return {
                    value: value,
                    data: key
                };
        })
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: thanks again but there is no source parameter [link](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete)

Comment: sorry, thought you were using jquery-ui autocomplete.  I can't visit your link, but regardless, the plugin you are using must provide some way to trigger the ajax call on each keypress.  Currently, your code doesn't refresh the lookup array on each keypress.